# Эксклюзивный порт для кластерного воркера в nodejs

Tags: node.js, port, cluster

Существует ли метод, чтобы открыть эксклюзивный порт для воркера в nodejs кластере. Т.е. например я хочу совместно использовать 80 порт, но при этом иметь на каждом воркере порт вида 300xx для непосредственного общения

Comment: А зачем вам direct communication с воркерами?

Comment: А теперь, тоже самое, но только по русский. Так как это русскоязычный сайт... And now, the same thing, but only in Russian. Since this is a Russian-language site ...

Comment: Хочется ) ну а если серьёзно - чтобы снимать статистику, и для межпроцессного взаимодействия.

Comment: @Gheljenor и вы хотите использовать для этого http?
https://github.com/sh84/node-ipc-test загляните сюда

Comment: Возможно tcp, я пока пытаюсь понять есть ли вообще принципиальная возможность это сделать или единственный способ использовать порт на мастере и ipc для передачи запроса в воркер

Comment: Никто не мешает запустить два http-сервера в одном воркере

Comment: Если я правильно понял документацию -  при этом оба порта будут шариться через мастер-процесс. В целом конечно если каждый воркер будет открывать свой порт,  общаться с ними можно будет по этим портам,  но при этом запрос будет проходить через мастер процесс,  что явлчется лишней нагрузкой и задержкой

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.bind({
  address: 'localhost',
  port: 8000,
  exclusive: true
});
```

[socket.bind(options[, callback])](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_socket_bind_options_callback)